# Create plpgsql function that Inserts one row for each item in an array into table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I need to create a plpgsql function that inserts one row for each item in an array into table.

For example:
`the_array` = `[1,2,3]`

The result after inserting `the_array` into `temp_table`:

```
col
----
1
2
3
```

I found the following code from the this link:
http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/insert-into-table-from-list-or-array-td3217891.html

```
INSERT INTO tmptab 
   SELECT v 
     FROM unnest(string_to_array('1,2,4,2,1',',')) g(v)
```

It works like a charm, but I do not understand the how this piece of code works. 
Could anyone explain it for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports Set Returning Function (second name is tabular function). Functions from this class returns a table instead scalar value. There are a lot of use cases - one use case is a function "unnest"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simple_srf(int)
RETURNS SETOF int AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..$1
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT i; -- push value to result
  END LOOP;
  RETURN; -- finish execution
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM simple_srf(3);
 simple_srf 
------------
          1
          2
          3
(3 rows)
```

Function "string_to_array" parse string using separator to array.

```
postgres=# select string_to_array('aaa*bbb*ccc','*');
 string_to_array 
-----------------
 {aaa,bbb,ccc}
(1 row)
```

Unnest is simple function, that transforms a array to table. A source code of this function in plpgsql can be:

```
-- use PostgreSQL 8.4 syntax for simplicity
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN array_lower($1,1) .. array_upper($1,1)
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT $1[i];
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

"Unnest" is a polymorphic set returned function. PostgreSQL supports more builtin srf (tabular) function - e.g. generic_series or generate_subscripts

A older implementation of "unnest" function was:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest(anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement AS $$
SELECT $1[i] FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1)) g(i)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

-- or with generate_subscripts
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest(anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement AS $$
/*
 * g is a table alias
 * i is a column alias
 */
SELECT $1[i] FROM generate_subscripts($1,1) g(i)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `string_to_array('1,2,4,2,1', ',')` creates an array from string, so you could use `ARRAY[1,2,4,2,1]` instead.

Function `unnest(array)` expands the array to a set of rows. So you have a set of five rows with integer in each of them.

The last part `g(v)` is needed because you need to name the set of rows and its column.

So the whole `unnest(string_to_array('1,2,4,2,1',','))` returns a set of rows with one column in each. And it is mapped to `g(v)`, so you can use `v` as the value.

If you had a table like `create table g(v integer);` and inserted there the rows with values: `1,2,4,2,1`, then you would achieve the same result with:

```
INSERT INTO tmptab 
   SELECT v 
     FROM g;
```